# Include and Call PDF File in vb.net (after Deployement)

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

Glad to see this site, Thanks guys for being active. :)

---

I have a problem in Visual Studio 2010/VB.Net

I have windows form in Visual Basic, I deployed the software(form) to one installer
Now I want to open My PDF file( i-e: Specific) with Button_Click_Event
I know that:

```
Process.Start("MyPDF.pdf")
```

But I dont know if user install my software in his PC so may be he install the software in C D or other directory, and also I dont know How to include PDF file in my project :)
Please suggest for me, I am searching this every where but failed so pl help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Add->Existing Item` on your Project.
 Then add the PDF File to your Project. 
Afterwards you have to set the Properties of the newly added file to the following:

[image: Item in Solution Explorer]

Now the file will be added to your "Output" Directory after you build your Project.

 Now use your `Process.Start("MyPDF.pdf")` call. It will open up, as it resides in the same directory.

Comment: You guys just rocks!!!
Thanks thanks you
Jazakallah for your time Mr.BastiOnWpf
I am successfully run now file from my local directory (i-e D:\)
Now if i deploy this so there isnt need of any other link, the local directory link is enough?
And MyPDF file is 5MB

Comment: Sorry! I am again disturbing you, as this is the same problem related to above so I didnt make new thread.
.
The problem is:
I want to distribute PDF file with my Windows form, thats Ok, I add 'MyPDF.pdf' in 'Resources', but after deplyement when i called by above method, so the 'MyPDF.pdf' dsnt open
So what can I do now plz help me

Answer (score 0):

This is rather easy:
Simply include the file by dragging it to your project folder and in its options, tell it to copy to the build directory.
Thereafter, find the path through the my.application methods.
Build a correct path from that and launch it via process.start

Comment: Oh Thanks!
@Christian Sauer
Thanks for ur kind reply
I have this screenshot you just take a look so i think this will be helpful for me and other users:
http://s4.postimg.org/rswv9566l/Stack_overflow.jpg

Comment: Sorry! I am again disturbing you, as this is the same problem related to above so I didnt make new thread.
.
The problem is:
I want to distribute PDF file with my Windows form, thats Ok, I add 'MyPDF.pdf' in 'Resources', but after deplyement when i called by above method, so the 'MyPDF.pdf' dsnt open
So what can I do now plz help me

Comment: What method do you use to deploy your application?

Comment: Oh, Thanks for ur reply Mr.@Christian Sauer:)
I use all the methods!
I check the New Project>> Other>>Visual Studio Installer>>Setup Wizard
and I also use the different softwares but still you know :(
So what can I do now?

Comment: I would guess, that the default VS Installers are NOT copying the file to your destination. Can you check if the file is present in the installed folder?If not, the WiX Installer may be an alternative.

Comment: I checked that!
The PDF file is installed/extracted there, but I dont know how to call that ?

Comment: This is my Form check it:
http://s4.postimg.org/rswv9566l/Stack_overflow.jpg
(ignore the Red text)
And my code is simple:
Process.Start("MyPDF.pdf")
or (I use one at one time)

'Process.Start("D:\QuestnAsk\Ask in StackOverflow\Ask in StackOverflow\Recources\MyPDF.pdf")

Comment: If the d:\QuestnAsk path is hardcoded this cannot work - the path has to be build, or simply set to "MypDF.pdf" like demonstrated in the post below.

Comment: Oh yeah! Thanks My problem is solved I will post link here
But the only problem now as:
When I deploy my software to both .exe and msi, so the .msi file is good and of expected size(8MB) but .exe have only 480KB space so this is now a problem
Sorry If I am so n00b in Vb.Net :p

Comment: This is Link for the same concept I answer my own question there, I am sure this will help you all: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15926111/want-to-distribute-pdf-file-with-my-visual-basic-project-during-deploying