# Want to Distribute PDF file with my Visual Basic Project during Deploying

Tags: vb.net, installation, vb.net-2010

I have Visual Basic (Visual Studio Professional Edition, .NetFrameWork 4.0)
I want to include and Call PDF with my `Button_Click_Even`t
I include MyPDF.pdf in `Resources` and after that I follow the link and call as:

> Process.Start("LinkTo\MyPDF.pdf")

but this is Ok and works, as this in my own PC, but when I install this in another PC (or I displace the PDF from the link as specified) so it fails to open the `MyPDF.pdf`

So My Question as What I did that during installation also `MyPDF.pdf` also install on user computer and which code I use for this?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, press on the pdf file in the solutions explorer. Propeties of the file should be as following:

```
Build Action: Content 
Copy to output directory: Copy always
```

The path to the file in users computer will be `Application.StartupPath & "\Resources\MyPDF.pdf"`

Not sure I did not forget something, so tell me if it works :)

---

**EDIT:**
I see a lot of people are having trouble with this so here is the simplest way I know to deploy a file together with .net program in visual studio:

1. Drag and drop the file to the solutions explorer
2. Press on the file in the solutions explorer and modify it's propeties to:

> Build Action: Content;
>   Copy to output directory: Copy always
>
> The path to the file to be used in code will be `Application.StartupPath & "\filename.txt"`
>
> I think there is a way to do it without Application.StartupPath, which may cause problems somehow, but i don't know how

Comment: No but this is not working the ("Application.StartupPath & \filename.txt"), I have checked the below method which is simply (Process.Start("filename.txt")) if you have file with the same as with form, and you can also use the (Process.Start("Resources\filename.txt")) if your file is in Resources folder. I am sure this is working because I also used this method, u can see my bellow answer. I distribute a pdf whose size was 6mb. Thanks for ur info :)

Comment: Well it worked for me, I tested it while writting. I just had made a mistake here, it had to be Application.StartupPath & "\filename.txt", not "Application.StartupPath & \filename.txt". I have now corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

Wah!!! Great And finally I am able to open any file in other machine 
I did this by ordinary methods so I was failed I am going to explain for those who wana learn:
 
`1)=` I add PDF file by clicking on properties in `solution explorer`, then I select `Resources`, In Resources I add "Add Existing Item" So PDF is added to my project in "`Resources`" folder

`2)=` After that I click on PDF in solution explorer and Change Build Action to : Content (even none also works) and Copy to output directory to: Copy always (As suggested by you :))

`3)=` So whats wrong, actually compiler make folder outside `bin` folder and we all paste only `Release` folder(when we deploying, I actually do this lol), so i just cut(Ctrl+X) `Resource` folder and paste inside in `Release` folder, and call by this code:

> Process.Start("Resources\MyPDF.pdf")

I am sure if we copy the PDF file directly in Release folder so this will also work with this code:

> Process.Start("MyPDF.pdf")

I am sure this will help for those who are in search of this!
Thank you guys who help me. Jazakallah